# Dragging in Google Sheets returns an unwanted result

Tags: google-sheets, autocomplete

I'm making a weekly calendar on Google Sheets. I've prepared the first week and I wanted to select and drag it down to generate automatically the next weeks but the values I get are not what I want.

this is what I'm getting:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/79k92.png

and this is what I would like to get:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXQ8P.png

the dates are in this format: `=$C$6 + n`  (i take the reference from cell C6 and add 1 every next day on the calendar)

The day number is just a text

I tried to search online and in stackoverflow but found nothing useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for what you are trying to do is in two parts:

1. Fix date rows (row 8 and row 13)
2. Fix day count rows (row 9 and row 14)

First of all, fix your date rows

1:
**Row8**

- C8: =C6
- D8: =C8+1
- E8: =D8+1
- F8: =E8+1
- G8: =F8+1
- H8: =F8+1
- I8: =H8+1

1: **Row13**

- C13: =I8+1
- D13: =C13+1
- E13: =D13+1
- F13: =E13+1
- G13: =F13+1
- H13: =F13+1
- I13: =H13+1

Once you have done it, fix your day count rows (the day's formulas have the same logic as the date formulas. The day formula takes the last word of the previous day, increments it by 1, and adds the word "Giorno " before the number you got)

2: **Row9**

- C9: Giorno 1
- D9: =CONCAT("Giorno "; TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(C9;" ";REPT(" ";LEN(C9)));LEN(C9)))+1)
- E9: =CONCAT("Giorno "; TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(D9;" ";REPT(" ";LEN(D9)));LEN(D9)))+1)
- F9: =CONCAT("Giorno "; TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(E9;" ";REPT(" ";LEN(E9)));LEN(E9)))+1)
- G9: =CONCAT("Giorno "; TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(F9;" ";REPT(" ";LEN(F9)));LEN(F9)))+1)
- H9: =CONCAT("Giorno "; TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(G9;" ";REPT(" ";LEN(G9)));LEN(G9)))+1)
- I9: =CONCAT("Giorno "; TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(H9;" ";REPT(" ";LEN(H9)));LEN(H9)))+1)

2: **Row14**

- C14: =CONCAT("Giorno "; TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(I9;" ";REPT(" ";LEN(I9)));LEN(I9)))+1)
- D14: =CONCAT("Giorno "; TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(C14;" ";REPT(" ";LEN(C14)));LEN(C14)))+1)
- E14: =CONCAT("Giorno "; TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(D14;" ";REPT(" ";LEN(D14)));LEN(D14)))+1)
- F14: =CONCAT("Giorno "; TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(E14;" ";REPT(" ";LEN(E14)));LEN(E14)))+1)
- G14: =CONCAT("Giorno "; TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(F14;" ";REPT(" ";LEN(F14)));LEN(F14)))+1)
- H14: =CONCAT("Giorno "; TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(G14;" ";REPT(" ";LEN(G14)));LEN(G14)))+1)
- I14: =CONCAT("Giorno "; TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(H14;" ";REPT(" ";LEN(H14)));LEN(H14)))+1)

At this point, if you select the area from cell B12 to cell I16, you can drag it down using the little blue square in the bottom-right of your selected area to automatically make new weeks.

Answer (score 0):

You are copying rows of data by **`dragging diagonally`** but data values are not incrementing as you expect:

The solution is in two parts:

1. Build two sets of rows. These are described below.

   - Set#1 is fixed;
   - Set#2 can be copied down the sheet and will update accurately for each new set
2. Do **NOT** `drag diagonally`

   - the range in set#2 **MUST** by copied and then pasted.

**Set#1:Row8**

- C8: =C6
- D8: =C8+1
- E8: =D8+1
- F8: =E8+1
- G8: =F8+1
- H8: =F8+1
- I8: =H8+1

**Set#2:Row13**

- C13: =I8+1
- D13: =C13+1
- E13: =D13+1
- F13: =E13+1
- G13: =F13+1
- H13: =F13+1
- I13: =H13+1